# What is the official name for this metal bracket that sits on top of a concrete pier?

Tags: exterior, foundation

What is the official name for this metal bracket that sits on top of a concrete pier?

[image: What is this called?]

Comment: Why the down vote?  Is this not an appropriate question to ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post anchor is what I have always heard them called.  However, Home Depot stores sell them as a [Post Base](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/catalog/servlet/Search?langId=-1&catalogId=10053&keyword=post+anchor&Ns=None&Ntpr=1&Ntpc=1&selectedCatgry=Search+All).

Answer (score 2):

This is a post-base anchor for what looks to be a 4x4 post.

They come in different sizes and types.  This particular kind has a bolt on the bottom that sinks into the concrete by at least 4 inches to secure it to the concrete.